# How would i make a contract that only let mint the actual nft by owning other nfts

Tags: nft, contract

I create a game where users can get 'welcome' tokens for free. When they like to get another token (nft) from the game, it is only possible to mint when the user already has a 'welcome' token.

Basically, how to make a dependency to mint a specific token ONLY when another specific token or one of a collection or wallet address is already owned. Or is that not done within the contract but rather with a separate API call to check before calling the mint option?

I am new, so I hope you can help with some examples. Thanks, christian

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the welcome collection is ERC-721, you can use its `balanceOf()` standardized method of ERC-721. This method gives you the total amount of NFTs that the user holds in the queried collection.

Or you can use the `ownerOf()` standardized function if you want to check if the user is owner of a specific token ID in the specific collection.

EIP: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

contract WelcomeCollection is ERC721 {
    constructor() ERC721("Welcome", "Welcome") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1);
    }
}

contract OtherCollection is ERC721 {
    IERC721 welcomeCollection;

    // Pass the Welcome collection address to your contract
    constructor(IERC721 _welcomeCollection) ERC721("Other", "Other") {
        welcomeCollection = _welcomeCollection;
    }

    function mint__checkAny() external {
        // The contition succeeds only if the user owns at least 1 NFT of Welcome collection
        require(welcomeCollection.balanceOf(msg.sender) != 0, "Not allowed");

        // TODO your own logic for assigning the Other collection token IDs
        _mint(msg.sender, 1);
    }

    function mint__checkSpecific() external {
        // The condition succeeds only if the user owns token ID 1 of the Welcome collection
        require(welcomeCollection.ownerOf(1) == msg.sender, "Not allowed"); 

        // TODO your own logic for assigning the Other collection token IDs
        _mint(msg.sender, 2);
    }
}
```